# How to insert code before matched multi-line of code with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, debian, sed

I want to add this code

```php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|phpmyadmin)$';
```

into phpMyAdmin's **config.inc.php** file **before** the line

```php
/**
 * End of servers configuration
```

###### Expect result:

```php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|phpmyadmin)$';

/**
 * End of servers configuration
 */
```

---

Here is sample of **config.inc.php** file ( https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/config.sample.inc.php )

My current `sed` code in **.sh** file is

```
#!/bin/sh

PHPMATARGETDIR="/var/www/phpmyadmin"

sudo sed -i "s/\(\/\*\*\)/ #my code before;\n\1/" ${PHPMATARGETDIR}/config.inc.php
```

but it is not working, it's just prepend to all open comment block.

If I use this code then it is not working at all.

```
sudo sed -i "s/\(\/\*\*\n\s*\* End of servers configuration\)/ #my code before;\n\1/" ${PHPMATARGETDIR}/config.inc.php
```

Comment: sed works on a single line at a time, so your "not working at all" solution is doomed to failure. It can probably be rescued by saying "every time you see an open comment block, append the next line onto the pattern space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in sed:

```
sed "/\/\*\*/{
N
/ \* End of servers config/i\
\$cfg['Servers'][\$i]['hide_db'] = '^(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|phpmyadmin)\$';
}" config.inc.php
```

Note that your provided `config.inc.php` actually contains

```
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */
```

**without** the double-asterisk - it would probably be safer to make the first expression `/\/\*/` and the second simply `/End of servers config/`

Comment: Sorry, the original by phpMyAdmin is `/**` not `/*`. I'll test your code today. Thank you

Comment: It seems to work but it just echo out without write to the file.

Comment: @vee From reading your question, you seem to know how to use `-i` with `sed`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh, thanks. I have to add `sudo` before `sed` and use `-i` with that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use perl bash as taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252020/128761) and [this reference](https://superuser.com/questions/416419/perl-for-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-terminal).

```
PHPMATARGETDIR="/var/www/phpmyadmin"

ADDPMACONFIG="\$cfg['Servers'][\$i]['hide_db'] = '^(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|phpmyadmin|sys)\$';"
ADDPMACONFIG=$(printf '%s\n' "$ADDPMACONFIG" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.|()^[]/\\&/g')
sudo perl -0777 -i -p -e "s/(\/\*\*\n\s+\*\s+End of servers configuration.*)/${ADDPMACONFIG}\n\1/" ${PHPMATARGETDIR}/config.inc.php
```